# Custom document Editor with Angular( Syncfusion document editor replica)

Tags: angular, editor, contenteditable, syncfusion, jsoneditor

I would like to make a document editor with angular from scratch to integrate it in an angular application instead of Syncfusion document editor. Also want to use JSON for controls instead of HTML.
Any type of help will be appreciated. This might me a hint to move forward.

This custom document editor should be able to format and edit any type of document, especially word documents. One example could be this textarea element in which I am writing this content right now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Document Editor component is used to create, edit, view, and print Word documents in web applications. All the user interactions and editing operations that run purely in the client-side provides much faster editing experience to the users.

Overview: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/document-editor/

Document editor requires server side interaction for following action:

Open file formats other than SFDT
Paste with formatting
Restrict editing
Spellcheck
Save as file formats other than SFDT and DOCX
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/document-editor/#supported-platforms-for-server-side-dependencies

You can deploy web APIs for server-side dependencies of Document Editor component in the following platforms.

ASP.NET Core
ASP.NET MVC
Java

Documentation link:https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/document-editor/web-services/

Other than above, remaining functionalities will work without server side interaction.